# Laravel how to add a custom function in an Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a Product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    ...

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Price');
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to add a function which will return the lowest price, and in controller I can get the value using:

```
Product::find(1)->lowest;
```

I added this in Product model:

```
public function lowest()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```

but I got an error saying:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

And if I use `Product::find(1)->lowest();`, it will work. Is it possible to get `Product::find(1)->lowest;` to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no ofc because you are calling a method i think tgat will work only for a hasone relation ,and what is the difference? with () or without!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you try to access a function in the model as a variable, laravel assumes you're trying to retrieve a related model. They call them dynamic properties. What you need instead is a custom attribute.

**Before Laravel 9**

Laravel 6 docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators

add following method to your model:

```
public function getLowestAttribute()
{
    //do whatever you want to do
    return 'lowest price';
}
```

Now you should be able to access it like this:

```
Product::find(1)->lowest;
```

**EDIT: New in Laravel 9**

Laravel 9 offers a new way of dealing with attributes:

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

```
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

public function lowest(): Attribute
{
     return new Attribute(
        get: function( $originalValue ){
         //do whatever you want to do
         //return $modifiedValue;
      });

     /**
      * Or alternatively:-
      *
      * return Attribute::get( function( $originalValue ){
      *    // do whatever you want to do
      *    // return $modifiedValue;
      * });
      */
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that with attributes that weren't defined as columns in the underlying table;  the documentation didn't mention that (that I could find).

Comment: Hello I would also be interested to know where you I could find this in the Laravel documentation. Thanks.

Comment: i think this needs to be lowest(); -- i get a relationship error without that ending '()'

Comment: @sanders you can find it under [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: So basically, you have to do `get` + property-name-with-first-letter-capitalized + `Attribute()` to get what you want? That's confusing, but works. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Use Eloquent [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

```
public function getLowestAttribute()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```

Then

```
$product->lowest;
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use above methods or use following method to add a function direct into existing model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';

    // get detail by id
    static function detail($id)
    {
        return self::find($id)->toArray();
    }

    // get list by condition
    static function list($name = '')
    {
        if ( !empty($name) ) return self::where('name', 'LIKE', $name)->get()->toArray();
        else return self::all()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Or use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; inside your function. Hope this help others.

Comment: How do you access these methods?  Is it `Company::detail(2);` or `Company::list('Company 1')`?

Comment: @HalfMens yes, try do this

Comment: Thanks.  The main thing is that the method should be `static` otherwise you get an error: `Non-static method App\Models\Company::detail(2) should not be called statically`

Comment: Sure, if you want to call it directly. Otherwise Company::where()->detail() or something others static method is avaiable in laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Why you just don't do this? I know, it's not what you asked for specifically and it might be a bad practice sometimes. but in your case, I guess it's good.

```
$product = Product::with(['prices' => function ($query) {
   $query->min('price');
}])->find($id);
```

Comment: i know, i just gave him a second aproache.

Comment: Please, where is this in the documentation? I want to read more about this

Comment: here you go buddy [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 2):

change follow code

```
public function lowest()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```

to

```
// add get as prefix and add posfix Attribute and make camel case function
public function getLowestAttribute()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```