# I can not add methods to User Model in Laravel 5.4 ..!

Tags: php, laravel, methods, model

I'm using Laravel 5.4. I have the methods I created in the User model. When I want to create an object from the User model and invoke my own methods, I can not get to the methods I added.

The User Model is derived from the Authenticable class at 5.4, which was derived earlier from the Model class. I think the problem is about it. What I really want to do is to set up the belong_to, has_many structure to relate the user model to the other models.

But with the User model I do not do that. What do you recommend ?

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getMakale()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Makale::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }    

}

    $author = User::first();
    return  method_exists($author,'getMakale');
```

//eventually turns false

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692482/laravel-how-to-add-a-custom-function-in-an-eloquent-model

Comment: it was not what I wanted

Comment: in short you want to create a relation with other models but you do not want to call these models as  relation, but  you trying to simply call the method that creates the connection? And why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are potentially [setting an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) rather than a relationship. In this case I would think you want to name that function something like:

```
public function haberler()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Makale::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

or `public function makales()`. Prefixing your function name with `get` or `set` will have unintended consequences in Laravel.