# Switching from Limit() to First() in Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm stuck on an issue where I'm trying to clean up code presented to me, and I feel like I must've just been at this too long and can't see this issue.

At the moment I have the following code in one of my models:

```php
public function attachments(){
    return $this->hasMany(volunteerAttachment::class, 'volunteerID','id');
}

 public function photoID() {
    $photoID= $this->attachments()->where('category','Drivers License')->orderBy('endDate','desc')->limit(1);
    return $photoID;
}
```

What I would like to do is what I believed was relatively simple in replacing the `limit(1)` of the function `photoIdentification` with a simple `first()`.

But when I try that and simply put `{{$volunteer->photoID->id}}` in my blade, it simply returns the error `App\volunteer::photoID must return a relationship instance`.

I do however know that there is a relationship because if I continue to use the `limit(1)` and put:

```php
@foreach($volunteer->photoID as $id) 
   {{$id->id}}
@endforeach
```

It returns the relation and document correctly.

`$volunteer` is the variable for that particular model `App\volunteer`, and the following is how it is defined in the controller:

```php
    public function show(Volunteer $volunteer){
            return view('volunteer.show', compact('volunteer'));
    }
```

Comment: What is `$volunteer`.

Comment: `$volunteer` is just the variable for that particular model App\volunteer.

Comment: This does not help, edit your question and add everything related to your problem.

Comment: Well, besides the controller, which I've just included, everything is there. As I said, it works one was where it is returned as a collection, but not the second way (with the first) where it should return a single instance.

Comment: I think this could be related [add Custom function to Laravel Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692482/laravel-how-to-add-a-custom-function-in-an-eloquent-model). Try to use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) instead

Comment: @Alberto - Thank you so much! You pointed me in the right direction and I got it to work. Would you like to post this as your answer so I can accept it? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post comtents of Volunteer model ?

Answer (score 1):

The function `photoID()` will still return a full `volunteerAttachment` object. If you want to get the id using the `first()` function you will have to select the `id` property on the object like so:

```
{{ $volunteer->photoID()->id }}
```

You could also [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on the model that directly returns this property:

```
public function getPhotoidAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attachments()->where('category','Drivers License')->orderBy('endDate','desc')->first()->id;
}
```

Now in blade you can just use:

```
{{ $volunteer->photoid }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function of a model as a variable Laravel assumes you try to return a related model. Try with an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) instead:

```
public function getPhotoidAttribute($value) {
    $photoID= $this->attachments()->where('category','Drivers License')->orderBy('endDate','desc')->first();
    return $photoID->id;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
{{ $volunteer->photoid }}
```